# Seed with Entity Framework Core autogenerate ID for partial entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I have a project in .NET 8 using Entity Framework Core. In the seed of the database, I have this code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreDictionaryWord>().HasData(
    new StoreDictionaryWord { ID = 1, Name = "1" },
    new StoreDictionaryWord { ID = 2, Name = "2" },

    new StoreDictionaryWord { Name = "3" },
);
```

In one specific entity, I have some new values with a defined `ID` but for other I don't mind the value of the `ID`. The `ID` is defined as

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public long ID { get; set; }
```

I read that it is possible to write something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreDictionaryWord>(entity =>
{
    entity. Property(e => e.ID).ValueGeneratedNever();
    entity.HasData(new StoreDictionaryWord{ Id = -1, Name = "Test" });
    entity. Property(e => e.ID).UseIdentityColumn();
});
```

So, I rewrite the code like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreDictionaryWord>(entity =>
{
    entity. Property(e => e.ID).ValueGeneratedNever();
    entity.HasData(
        new StoreDictionaryWord { ID = -1, Name = "1" },
        new StoreDictionaryWord { ID = -1, Name = "2" },
    );
    entity. Property(e => e.ID).UseIdentityColumn();
}
```

But when I create the migration, I get this error:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The seed entity for entity type 'StoreDictionaryWord' cannot be added because another seed entity with the same key value for {'ID'} has already been added. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

and the link is not useful at all. I get the same error if I omit the `ID`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Identity columns don't autoincrement when seeding with `HasData`. Why are you setting the ID to -1?